# brew install OpenCV for macOS arm

Tags: macos, opencv, arm, homebrew

i am using macOS arm, and install OpenCV for c++ using this command:

```
brew install --build-from-source OpenCV
```

download packages completed, and then i get this error:

```
==> Installing OpenCV
Error: An exception occurred within a child process:
  RuntimeError: Unexpected architecture: arm64. This only works with Intel architecture.
```

can you help me?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Clone sources

```
git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git
```

Create build directory

```
mkdir -p build && cd build
```

Configure

```
cmake ../opencv
```

Build

```
cmake --build .
```

Answer (score 1):

This command should work as well.

```
brew install opencv
```

If this command shows any error you may share.